# How to find the area of the given figure

Tags: area, curves

I have tried doing this

$dA = ydx [AC = y, BC = x]$

$y/x = (5 (\pi)/2)/5$

$y = (\pi/2)x$

$dA = (\pi/2)x (dx)$

$A = \int_0^5   \pi (x)/2 (dx)$

$A = 25 \pi/4$

but the answer is 5.4[image]

Here the curve is a quarter-circle

Comment: Please use mathjax for typesetting your math. I did one for you.

Comment: What's the curve supposed to be? Is it a quarter-circle?

Comment: Which is the equatioin for the curve? A hiperbole? If so, it seems more to be $xy=5\pi /2$

Comment: @Milten its an arc of a circle and not quarter-circle i forgot to mention it there

Comment: *An arc of a circle.* How many radians does it extends? What is $5\pi/2$ its radius? its length?

Comment: what is $\frac{5\pi}{2}$ ? the length of the arc?

Comment: The answer should be $25-25\pi/4\approx 5.4$ If it’s a square minus a quarter circle

Comment: Sounds like $5\pi/2$ is length of the arc. Can you write down the equation of that circle?

Comment: " i forgot to mention it there" Then you forgot to say *anything*.  If we don't know what the curve is the question is utterly meaningless.  Meanwhile what the heck does $\frac {5\pi}2$ refer to?  If it's an arc of a circle *which* circle.  The different arcs for different circles will have different answers.   No-one can answer *anything* if we don't know what the question is.

Comment: Can you use polar/parametric coordinates or must use cartesian coords?

Comment: @fleablood hmm, this question was given by my friend so i think its meaningless cause as you said arc of which circle as it depends upon the circle and he didn't gave any other info other than this, I am sorry for posting an incomplete question and I might as well delete it or re-edit with making the curve as a quarter-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data is unclear. So i will describe the area that i will compute in the sequel, then do this in "two different ways".

---

It seems that we have to calculate the area of the difference $Q-D'$, where

- $Q$ is the compact, full square with vertices in $(0,0)$, $(5,0)$, $(5,5)$, and $(0,5)$, and
- $D'$ is one quarter of the disk $D$ centered in $(5,5)$ with radius $5$. So $D'=D\cap Q$. The length of the quarter circle is indeed $5\pi/2$.

We expect to obtain the area $5^2-\frac 14\pi\cdot 5^2=5^2\left(1-\frac\pi4\right)$. Numerically, this is $5.36504591506379\dots$, and fits the  approximation $5.4$ from the OP.

---

Using differential and integral methods, the function to be considered is $f:[0,5]\to[0,5]$, $f(x)=5-\sqrt{5^2-(5-x)^2}$. This is extracted from the equation of the circle with center $(5,5)$ and radius $5$, isolating $y$ in $(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2$, and taking the right sign of the square root.

Note that this is **not** the function $g(x)=\sqrt{5^2-x^2}$, obtained from isolating $y$ in $x^2+y^2=5^2$, which would be the "other quarter circle" passing through $(5,0)$ and $(0,5)$. (This would be the reflection of the drawn arc taken w.r.t. the segment from $(5,0)$ to $(0,5)$.) Using $g$ we of course get $\frac 14\pi 5^2=25\pi/4$... The wrong answer mentioned in the OP.

So we compute the "area $A$ under the graph" of $f$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &=
\int_0^5f(x)\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^5\left(5-\sqrt{5^2-(5-x)^2}\right)\; dx
\qquad\text{Substitution: }x=5-5\cos t
\\
&
=25-\int_0^{\pi/2}
\sqrt{5^2-5^2\cos^2t}\; d(5-5\cos t)
\\
&=25-\int_0^{\pi/2}
5\sin t\; 5\cos t\; dt
=25-25\int_0^{\pi/2}
\sin^2 t\; dt
\\
&=
25\left(1-\frac \pi 4\right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The area of the square is $5^2$, and the area of the circle is $\pi5^2$.  To find the enclosed area, subtract a quarter of the area of the circle from the area of the square.